# Print/Read a line cache objects

Tags: intersystems-cache

I would like to read a line in cache class. I can read a line in cache routine using ZLOAD and PRINT. But I am not able to acheive the same in cache class. Please Help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Cache classes stored not like routines. You can read some parts of classes separately: Properties, Parameters, Methods and etc. And you can read implementation any method like this:

```
s methodDef=##class(%Dictionary.MethodDefinition).%Open("some.class||MyMethod")
d methodDef.Implementation.OutputToDevice()
```

For more information, you can read in documentation in classes of package [%Dictionary](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Dictionary)